# Pandas DataFrame: difference between rolling and expanding function

Tags: python, pandas

Can anyone help me understand the difference between rolling and expanding function from the example given in the pandas docs.

```
df = DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4]})
df
     B
0  0.0
1  1.0
2  2.0
3  NaN
4  4.0


df.expanding(2).sum()
     B
0  NaN  # 0 + NaN
1  1.0  # 1 + 0
2  3.0  # 2 + 1
3  3.0  # ??
4  7.0  # ?? 

df.rolling(2).sum()
     B
0  NaN  # 0 + NaN
1  1.0  # 1 + 0
2  3.0  # 2 + 1
3  NaN  # NaN + 2
4  NaN  # 4 + NaN
```

I give comment to each row to show my understanding of the calculation. Is that true for `rolling` function? What about `expanding`? Where are 3 and 7 in 3rd and 4th rows coming from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2 in `expanding` is `min_periods` not the `window`

```
df.expanding(min_periods=1).sum()
Out[117]: 
     B
0  0.0
1  1.0
2  3.0
3  3.0
4  7.0
```

If you want the same result with `rolling` `window` will be equal to the length of dataframe

```
df.rolling(window=len(df),min_periods=1).sum()
Out[116]: 
     B
0  0.0
1  1.0
2  3.0
3  3.0
4  7.0
```

Comment: Ah ok. Then `min_periods = 1` will differ `min_periods=2` in the 0th row. But I still don't understand: if `min_periods=2` , why `expanding` has 3 and 7 in 3rd and 4th row  resp.?

Comment: @bakka sum all previous value until the current row (included the current one )

Comment: @bakka it will be 0+1+2+NaN(3) and 0+1+2+NaN +4 (7)

Comment: hm.. so in my `rolling` example, `NaN` in 3rd row is not from `NaN + 2`?

Comment: @bakka your rolling is right  what I mentioned is for expeanding

Comment: If my rolling is right then why `0+1+2+NaN = 3` while `NaN+2 = NaN`?

Comment: @bakka you need `df.rolling(2,min_periods=1).sum()`