# What are pandas' `rolling` and `expanding` doing?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, rolling-computation

Coming from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53198344/pandas-dataframe-difference-between-rolling-and-expanding-function), which asks for the *difference* of `rolling` and `expanding`, I want to go one step more to the basics: what are `rolling` and `expanding` doing?

By preparing this question, I (hopefully) figured out that the i-th element of `df.rolling(n).func()` is the output of the function `func()` applied to the rows `(i-n):i` (a so called *window*) of `df`.

`expanding` applies the function to a window of varing size: `0:i`. My question is, whether my assumptions are correct and what is the practical use of `expanding`.

Comment: This would be more appropriate for https://stats.stackexchange.com/.  This isn't `pandas` specific, it's just basic statistics.  Ask what the difference is between a fixed moving window and an expanding window, it might have already been asked.

Comment: If you want the minimal pandas answer, your assumption is correct.  Rolling will take into account a fixed width window of the previous `n` values, while expanding takes into account all previous values in scope.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. Practical use of `expanding`, for example, is `expanding().sum()` which is equivalent to `cumsum()`. Another example is Mean Average Precision, which is more or less `expanding().mean()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas DataFrame: difference between rolling and expanding function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53198344/pandas-dataframe-difference-between-rolling-and-expanding-function)

Comment: @ItamarMushkin No, the question you link, is the same that I linked. My question is about the basic difference between 'rolling' and 'expanding'

Comment: @QuangHoang so, in your example ('expanding().sum() == cumsum()'), there is no use of 'expanding' since there exists 'cumsum'; but if I want to do something that is non-standard, I might need 'expanding'? If you want you can make your comments an answer I can accept.